# How do I prevent roslaunch from changing the terminal screen title?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use a series of bash scripts to run multiple applications on my robot at once. Many of the scripts spawn extra terminals that call a single `roslaunch` each. My problem is that I need to be able to distinguish the terminals by the title bar at the top.

[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687642/set-screen-title-from-shellscript)  shows how to set the screen title in a bash script, but the problem is that roslaunch always renames the title if I change it before, and I can't change it until after the roslaunch node has quit and it is no longer useful to me.

Is there any good way of changing the title within the roslaunch parameters?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199845/how-do-i-prevent-roslaunch-from-changing-the-terminal-screen-title?/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i don't think that is exposed to be updated by the user. If it's worth enough to you. I'm sure we'd be willing to merge an enhancement which allowed parametrizing that entry.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-12-29**:
It's probably not worth the hassle--and I wouldn't know how to modify it myself. Thanks for the answer!